# Pairing two BLE Devices with the same UUID (with CoreBluetooth)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have two `BLE devices` with the same `UUID`. Is there any way to connect to both of them so that they are both connected at the same time?

Right now I'm not able to even see both devices simultaneously using a `bluetooth explorer`, so I assume for the system they appear as just one device. Is it still somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that with UUID you mean the MAC-Address (Bluetooth address) of the device. UUIDs are typically used for services and characteristics.

All connection procedures work with the Bluetooth address as the main parameter. So two devices with the same address will be treated as the same device. (In fact, it is a common requirement that MAC-Addresses of Bluetooth devices should be unique, exactly for this reason.)

So it is not possible to connect to two devices with the same address at the same time. (*)

You can find more information about how connection is done in the Bluetooth Core Spec, Vol. 3, Part C, chapter 9.3.5 - 9.3.8.

(*) This is meant in the common way of having a connection to two different devices. Since incoming messages are not distinguishable on Link Layer level between the two devices with identical address (your control will always think there is only one device with the given address out there), you could mess around with this fact, especially in non-encrypted connections (since encryption is negotiated on a device-to-device basis, another device could not join in an encrypted connection, even if it has the same Bluetooth address). But it is definitely not recommended to do so.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, I meant the MAC-Adress. In iOS every device is given a UDID by the system, so in the code you can always distinguish between multiple devices by their UDIDs. These UDIDs are similar to the UDIDs of the services and characteristics. After testing with two devices with the same MAC/UDID I found out, that I couldn't connect with both devices at the same time, not on iOS and not on Android.

Answer (score 1):

If two devices are having the same UUID , then I think they would be consider as a single device. What I would suggest , send a trigger notification to the UUID and check which device will respond first . Secondly , try to send notification to devices put them far apart . The nearer to your smartphone/bluetooth explorer , will get notify first . Bluetooth works on the distance basis, the device which is near to the source will get the notification than the other one.I tried the same with Beacons but end up like you.

Comment: Well. Even with different MAC (The Bluetooth address). I found that during the advertising, iOS won’t treat them as different devices. For privacy reasons, iOS filters out the Bluetooth address which is in the advertising packet. I am working on a solution for my iOS app to “see” them. Right now my App thinks there is only one unit is advertising.